# AsyncTask without callback interface

Tags: java, android, callback, android-asynctask

I'm trying to resolve this problem: I have a class that extends from AsyncTask, that execute some http methods, something like this:

```
    public class RESTManager extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String>
{
    public RESTManager(String url, MethodTypes myMethod,ICallbackHandler hndl, String     restMethod)
    {
        initialize();
    }

    private String doGET()
    {
    }

    private String doPOST()
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params)
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
    }

}
```

So, from Activity I' doing this:

```
RESTManager webService = new WSManager(URL, MethodTypes.REGISTER, params, this, WSManager.GET_METHOD);
webService.execute();
```

And then the activity receives the response in the callbak method (because activity implements this interface):

```
public void response(String response)
{
    // some process
}
```

This is working ok, but my problem is that I would like that the answer comes in the same call to some function, and then that function calls the .execute method, for example.

```
// This is a new class
public class MyWebServices()
{
    public User getUser(int id)
    {
        User myUser;

        RESTManager webService = new WSManager(URL, MethodTypes.REGISTER, params, this, WSManager.GET_METHOD);
        webService.execute();

        // BUT I WANT TO RETURN FROM HERE THE CALL FROM THE ACTIVITY....LIKE

        return myUser;
    }
}
```

So from the activity this will be:

```
MyWebServices myService = new MyWebServices();
User usr = myService.getUser(id);
```

Hope undestand what I tried to describe, thanks!

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, what is a future object?

Comment: No need for apologies. This is S.O.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Answer (score 1):

What you want leads to blocking UI. Android doesn't allow you to do that. Network calls SHOULD be asynchronous, so the approach is wrong. Deal with `response()` method.

**UPD**: Blocking UI leads to "Application not responsive dialog" which annoys users. Also, what if the network call fails? Or it waits for half an hour to complete?

Comment: Yes, I now that, and agree. But what is the correct way to deal with the response? for example with a switch(wsMethodExecuted)? because each method has differents arguments (string, User object, List<User>, etc), so I would have to switch the methodExecuted and cast the argument in the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

learn to love callbacks :)

you cannot apply the pattern you mention (do in background, wait for result, return value) without blocking the UI thread.

the simplest thing is to simply implement the `onPostExecute()` method to call the thing you want to do after the REST call completes. you can however get more sophisticated, if you want to expose a clean interface to other parts of the system.

start by reading about the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). think of it this way: the completion of your REST call is an event, and code that is interested in that event can register to be notified (asynchronously) when it completes. you could do this my making your AsyncTask impl something like this,

```
AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask<...>() {
    public interface Callback {
        void onComplete();
        void onFailure();
    }

    private Set<Callback> callbacks = new HashSet<Callback>();

    public void addObserver(Callback cb) { callbacks.add(cb); }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        // whatever
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if (success) {
            for (Callback cb: callbacks) {
                cb.onComplete();
            }
        } else {
            for (Callback cb: callbacks) {
                cb.onFailure();
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

now, the consumer of this interface does something like,

```
MyTask mt = new MyTask();
mt.addObserver(new MyTask.Callback() { 
    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        // do whatever you want to do when the task completes successfully
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {
        // ...
    }
}

mt.execute();
```

Comment: ok, yes I love callbacks! just that sometimes I think the code is not clear or clean, but maybe is my perception. Besides, I not sure how to implement the code in the callback response method, because depending on the REST method that I called, the result (arguments) would be different, see my anser to Vladimir, and thanks! EDIT: in relation with arguments, argument type for onComplete() would be an Object type? and then cast it to the correct type depending on the REST method call?

Comment: the result of a REST call is the same regardless of the specific call. that is, it has a response code and a body. `onComplete()` can take these as arguments allowing the caller to check for errors and if it was successful, process the body result.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express very well, in the onPostexecute method, the string argument is the JSON string that I receive from the service, so I have to parse this to my correct object (so here I have to know who was the service I called to know the answer of that service) and then I have to pass this Object through onComplete method, probalby to the activity that call the service

Comment: well, a couple of options .. 1) have a unique AsyncTask for each call type, with an inner Callback for the specific response object type. 2) have all of your "response" objects extend from a common base and just pass that in to your callback method or 3) have the callback method just accept a string, and let the caller bind it to the specific response object type.